# Stuck at “Authenticating with the App Store...” when publishing my app

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

I am trying to publish my app on App Store, but it always stuck at “Authenticating with the App Store...”. I tried the Transporter app and `xcrun altool --upload-app` command, also googled many sites, the result are all the same. So how to resolve this issue?

My XCode version is 11.3

macOS version is 10.15.2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `iTMSTransporter` command can be quite slow sometime. You can: * Check your VPN / firewall with your sysadmin
* Have a try with another network (in-building or even a 4G shared connection) Did you already send an IPA thanks to this network ?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: I downloaded an old version of Application Loader and it was uploaded successfully.